# Understanding the Init in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider i create a Class Name "Application" which accepts "frame"  widget

```
class Application(Frame):
```

In Constructor/Initialisation i do

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
```

When creating Instance

```
root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
```

i dont Understand when creating instance i am assigning instance of class Tk() to Master . then why in initialisation we are making it "None". can Some one look into this and Explain.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `def __init__(self, master=None):` you are setting None as the *default* value of `master`.  When you call `Application(master=root)` you are passing a value that overrides the default.

```
A simple example:

def foo(a=1):
    print "a is", a

>>> foo()
a is 1
>>> foo(2)
a is 2
>>> foo(a=2)
a is 2
>>>
```

Comment: Hi !! thnks for explanation. is there any rule/documentation which explains this in more detail. i got the point but technically still i am not able to understand. when i make a call to foo(with no arguments) its fine a gets default value. but when i pass some argument still it should get default value. why the default value is ignored ??

Comment: @PragRao: When you pass a value, it overrides the default value.  That's what "default" means: it means its the value that is used if you don't specify any other value.  You can start with [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) for more info.